# struct INotifyPropertyChanged will not work with ctor

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I get the error message in design time

> PropertyChanged must be fully assigned

In the ctor.  If not ctor then not error message.

How to fix this?

```
public struct LogCurve : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void Notify()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<LogCurveDataPoint> LogPoints { get; }
    public int ServerCount { get; }
    public int Count { get { return LogPoints.Count; } }
    public double? MinValue
    {
        get
        {
            return LogPoints.Count == 0 ? (double?)null : LogPoints.Min(x => x.Value);
        }
    }
    public double? MaxValue
    {
        get
        {
            return LogPoints.Count == 0 ? (double?)null : LogPoints.Max(x => x.Value);
        }
    }
    public long? MinIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return LogPoints.Count == 0 ? (long?)null : LogPoints.Min(x => x.Index);
        }
    }
    public long? MaxIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return LogPoints.Count == 0 ? (long?)null : LogPoints.Max(x => x.Index);
        }
    }
    public LogCurve(string name, int serverCount)
    {
        Name = name;
        LogPoints = new List<LogCurveDataPoint>();
        ServerCount = serverCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but be careful: implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on a value type is almost certainly a bad idea. Value types may be copied in places where you don't expect it, making it very easy to subscribe to the wrong copy's changes.

Comment: @hvd I think I will switch over to class.

Comment: In fact a struct is copied evertime you provide it as a parameter to a method. Thus when you change the structs property-value only the copy ets notified, not your original reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All fields of a `struct` must be assigned in its constructor. This also applies to events. If you don't know what to do with the event field in the constructor, just set it to `null`:

```
public LogCurve(string name, int serverCount)
{
    Name = name;
    LogPoints = new List<LogCurveDataPoint >();
    ServerCount = serverCount;
    PropertyChanged = null;
}
```